# "Scary looks the future of AI" - Is this a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I was writing this sentence and it *feels* correct to me, but I am not sure. 
Can you guys share if the following sentence is grammatically sound and if it conveys the following meaning?

> Scary looks the future of AI

Intended semantic meaning: The future of AI looks scary

Comment: You _can_ construct a sentence like that, but only if you're being consciously archaic. Compare the King James Bible "Strait is the gate, and narrow is the way, which leadeth unto life" (Matthew 7:14)

Comment: It sounds like _Yoda-speak_ to me.

Comment: That's what I thought too @Cascabel thanks Kate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this correct: "Aloof the hallow{ed} things shall always be"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78592/is-this-correct-aloof-the-hallow-things-shall-always-be)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception to the word order S-V-O](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292140/exception-to-the-word-order-s-v-o)

Answer (score -1):

It might be considered correct (but awkward, unless it is in poetry) if you added a comma after "*Scary*".

As it stands, the first time one reads it, it's too easy to read "*Scary looks*" as the subject of the sentence and then stumble looking for the non-existent verb.