# Is it possible to start a sentence with "worse than"?

Tags: sentence, emphasis

In English, is it possible a sentence like this?

> Worse than those who *do something* are those who *do something else.*

I think this would be the standard sentence:

> Those who *do something else* are worse than those who *do something.*

But I was wondering if such syntax is possible to emphasize *what it's worse* in the sentence.

Comment: [is a sentence like this possible]. Yes, it's possible. Because: it is an inversion with the verb to be. This question may be closed or not. If not, I will put in an answer.

Comment: It's not only fine, it's good writing.

Comment: Better the syntax you know than the syntax you don't.

Comment: 'Worse than those who do nothing are those who do something stupid' is an example of inversion using a fronted predicative complement. The complement is weighty, though could reasonably in the right context be reduced to the adjective. At [exception to the word order S - V -](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292140/exception-to-the-word-order-s-v-o/292159#292159), John Lawler discusses Comp - Vcop - S inversions, noting that 'predicate adjective constructions don't reverse very well' (ie some sound dreadful). 'Worst of all are those who stop the real helpers.' / 'Tall is Tom.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Is ***Blessed are the meek*** also an example of a "fronted predicative complement"? If not, why not?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's a multiple translation and archaic to boot. That's not English syntax.

Comment: @FF Perhaps. Probably. 'The window was broken' is indeterminate between the verbal (punctive passive) and the best-regarded-as-adjectival stative readings. 'The window was broken by the falling rocket' v 'The window was broken/dirty, we found on arriving'. The passive reading would be unusual today with 'Blessed are ...', but in KJV times, I'm not sure. Probably still unidiomatic. Matt 11:5 reads: 'The blind receive their sight, and the lame walk, **the lepers are cleansed**, and the deaf hear, **the dead are raised up**, and the poor have the gospel preached to them.' No inversion.

Comment: "blessed are the meek" is an anastrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Worse than those who do something are those who do something else.*

Syntactically, this an example of subject-dependent inversion, where the adjectival predicative complement "worse than those who do something" is inverted with the subject "those who do something else".

This type of inversion puts the subject in final position, where it typically receives greater phonological prominence than in its basic position.